# How to configure MassTransit in an unreliable network environment?

Tags: c#-4.0, rabbitmq, masstransit, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm trying to get my head around MassTransit in combination with RabbitMQ.
The basic concepts are working in a test project, but what I need is the following:

My system will have one or more servers that react to real life events (telephony). These events wil, by means of MassTransit and RabbitMQ, translate into messages that will be picked up by one or more receivers via a separate server, set up as RabbitMQ host. So far so good.

However, I cannot assume that I always have a connection between the publisher and the host machines. Just assume that the publishing server will continue to consume the real life events, but now cannot publish it's messages.

So, the question is: Does MassTransit have some kind of mechanism to store messages locally some way until the connection is re-established?
Or should I install RabbitMQ on every publishing server as well, in order to create a local exchange? Then I have to make the exchanges synchronize themselves after a reconnect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to implement a *store and forward* policy. Instead of publishing directly your message through MassTransit and RabbitMQ, you can store the message in a persistence repository (a local database) and delegate to some other process the notification through Masstransit of the messages stored before. This approach is often referred as "Client High Availability". This does not substitute the standard HA (*High Availability*) on server like the one implemented by RabbitMQ. But it's a good approach to use in a distributed system (like the one you described) because it could help you a lot in scenarios of server failure  (e.g. an issue on RabbitMQ server that causes some loss of messages that you still have inside the store of some client and therefore you can make it process again).